# Recursive population of tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, minimax

I've been attempting to create and populate a tree in java, and then use the minimax algorithm to find the best course for an AI.

Recursive function to generate tree:

```
public void gen(Node n, int depth){ 
    if(depth == 6){
        n = new Node();  
        n.depth = height;
    }
    else{
        n = new Node();
        n.depth = depth;            
        gen(n.e1, depth+1);
        gen(n.e2, depth+1);
        gen(n.e3, depth+1);
        gen(n.p1, depth+1);
        gen(n.p2, depth+1);
         gen(n.p3, depth+1);
        }
    }
```

Function to populate tree with values:

```
public void score(Node node, char a){       
    //Assigning scores to states to find utility value
    //Changing state strings to reflect current state of nodes and phase
    if(node!=null && node.depth!=6){
           if(node.depth%2==1){
            //Player's turn
            node.state = node.state.substring(0, node.depth))+a+node.state.substring((node.depth+2));           
            score(node.e1, 'a');
            score(node.e2, 'b');
            score(node.e3, 'a');
            score(node.p1, 'b');
            score(node.p2, 'a');
            score(node.p3, 'b');
            }
            else if(node.depth%2==0){
            //AI's turn
            node.state = node.state.substring(0,(node.depth+4))+a+node.state.substring((node.depth+6));
            score(node.e1, 'a');
            score(node.e2, 'b');
            score(node.e3, 'a');
            score(node.p1, 'b');
            score(node.p2, 'a');
            score(node.p3, 'b');
            }
        }       
    }
```

Test function to see if everything worked, by printing the contents:

```
public void printTree(Node node){           
        if(node!=null){
            System.out.println(node.depth + " " + node.state);
            printTree(node.e1);
            printTree(node.e2);
            printTree(node.e3);
            printTree(node.p1);
            printTree(node.p2);
            printTree(node.p3);
        }
    }
```

And, the node class itself:
final class Node
{
    public String state = "BCXXXCXXX";

```
//utility value
public int score;
public int oscore;
public int utility;
public int min;
public int max;
public int depth;

Node p1;
Node p2;
Node p3;    
Node e1;
Node e2;
Node e3;

public Node()
{

}
```

}

I run the print function, and it prints
    1 BxXXCXXX
Which I expected for the first node. I called it with an empty node, and depth of 1. Why isn't it generating (or printing) the rest of the tree, down to depth 6?

Although I think this is possibly unrelated, this code will eventually be used in an Android game.

Comment: For the minimax algorithm, you shouldn't be building the tree at all. It should be implicit in the recursion pattern.

Comment: you should generate a path at a time, just like you do in a recursive DFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java passes `Node` by value, so your assignment `n = new Node();` has no effect. Your `gen` function should return the node it creates, instead of taking one as a parameter.

```
public Node gen(int depth){ 
    Node n = new Node();
    if (depth == 6){
        n.depth = height;
    } else {
        n.depth = depth;            
        n.e1 = gen(depth+1);
        n.e2 = gen(depth+1);
        n.e3 = gen(depth+1);
        n.p1 = gen(depth+1);
        n.p2 = gen(depth+1);
        n.p3 = gen(depth+1);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: The output did change, but I can't confirm if this did the trick, because my print function is now showing an endless loop. I'm new to Java, so is there something I'm doing wrong with that as well?

Comment: @zigzag90 That is unexpected. Could you share the first 30..40 lines of the printout?

Comment: My apologies, I was using an older version of the function. It worked well this time around. I'll try adding it to the overall project now, thanks!